# click function disturbing in IE

Tags: jquery

I have made simple click function but it is not working properly in IE. `I have two box first name is 'big'` and `second is 'small'` when you `click on big it will alert massage`. `Big is parent of 'small' box` so if you `click on small it will also alert`. Step to produce bug. Click on black div and dont leave mouse button drag it to red div it will not alert massage in firefox but it is alerting massage in IE. Example code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YLkXt/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.big').click(function () {
        alert(0)
    })
})
```

Comment: Could you please add the HTML code as well? So we can see how you intend to build 'big' and 'small'.

Comment: You are missing some semicolons...

Comment: Johan:semicolons are optional

Comment: logansama: I added fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YLkXt/

Comment: While the code will still work without semi-colons, they should be added and they may not be optional in IE.

Comment: small is inside the big box, so it will propagate the click event, check out the stop propagation

Comment: adbul: I have checked it but it is not working

Comment: I think this is just browser specific bug or setting you can't do anything about it. `click small and drag on big then leave the mouse button`

Comment: @Jai You can't say it is a bug, it is how they have implemented it

Comment: @ArunPJohny actually i didn't had a specific word about it that's why i mentioned `bug or setting`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want the alert to happen when the `.small` div is clicked?

To do that, you will need to stop the event propagation on the `.small` div click, like so:

```
$('.big').click(function(){
    alert(0);
});

$('.small').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dwqTU/3/

Comment: when you click on small div then dont leave mouse button and drag you mouse pointer to red div and leave mouse button. it is alerting massage

Comment: Try this, instead **click()** use **mousedown()** check here: [http://jsfiddle.net/dwqTU/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/dwqTU/5/)